# Google App Engine SDK: ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, virtualenv, mysql-python

I am trying to run my Django app on Google App Engine SDK (locally) inside a `virtualenv` with `MySQL` as a database. Everything in my `requirements.txt` file is installing perfectly. When I start the Google App Engine SDK environment, it throws me a nasty error that seems common, but Stack Overflow doesn't have any examples of solving this within Google App Engine SDK yet.

***Here is my work flow from the root dir of my project...***

`virtualenv venv && mkdir lib`

`source venv/bin/activate`

`pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/ && pip install -r requirements.txt`

***When I run the following command to start up the SDK....***

`dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

***I get the following error in my traceback...***

```
File "/Users/username/Repositories/projectname/lib/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Users/username/Repositories/projectname/lib/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
INFO     2018-06-26 20:09:30,812 module.py:846] default: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 500 -
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/username/Repositories/projectname/lib/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

***My requirements.txt***

```
Django==1.11.8
djangorestframework==3.8.2
facebook-sdk
oauth2client==2.0.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.2
facebookads==2.11.1
httplib2==0.10.3
enum==0.4.6
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
google-auth
requests==2.18.0
lxml==3.8.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

***Contents of `lib/`***
[image: Contents of <code>lib/</code>]

***I am calling MySQLdb in my app.yaml as well...***

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

***Contents of appengine_config.py***

```
# [START vendor]
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
# [END vendor]
```

***Some things I have checked off the list while debugging...***

1) `MySQL-python==1.2.5` is installed when I do a `pip freeze` in my virtual environment.

2) `MySQL` is installed and works perfectly on my local computer.

3) I've looked through the lionshare of Stack Overflow's questions thus far and none of them seem to help.

Comment: Can you show the content of your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @DanCornilescu just included the file in the edited question.

Comment: Are all the packages successfully installed in the `lib` dir? I just tried to install the same requirements and the installation failed with `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`. Side note - you don't need the second installation - `pip install -r requirements.txt` - the development server (and GAE) don't care about what's not in the `lib` dir (except for the few libs that *might* be needed to run the local server.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I've updated the question to contain the contents of my `lib/` directory. And yes, It appears that MySQL is there. I encountered that error too. I just had to enter the location of the path of my `MySQL` on my local machine to fix it. For example... `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`. It is just that GAE cannot find the MySQL header file `mysql_config`.

Comment: Given that [MySQLdb is a built-in library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27), it should be [called in the app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) rather than in requirements.txt

Comment: @ChristopherP I am currently calling it in my `app.yaml` file and also have it in my `requirements.txt`. Are you saying that there is no need to install mysql-python at all in requirements because Google Cloud SDK provides it?

Comment: The line `source venv` should normally be `source venv/bin/activate`. Does this command execute ok or does it return an error?

Comment: @void My bad, I am actually calling `source venv/bin/activate` and yes, it works fine.

Comment: You install the same set of libraries to both `venv` and `lib/`. What is the purpose of installing into `lib/` and how does it happen that GAE finds Django in the `lib/`? Do you have `PYTHONPATH` set up?

Comment: @void so per GAE's instructions, you need a lib folder to hold all your relevant libraries, especially when you deploy to the Google Cloud. So the lib folder is necessary. I am in fact installing all dependencies in both my lib folder and my venv. 

I am not sure what you mean by PYTHONPATH. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You run `dev_appserver.py` as a shebang script. It's first line contains `#!/usr/bin/env python` which means "launch me as if it was typed `python dev_appserver.py`". Since that happens in the activated virtual environment, the default python interpreter should be `venv/bin/python`. Without other special arrangements it will import all libraries from `venv/lib/python2.7/...`. Importing Django from `lib/` indicates that GAE does some trickery with the import path. I tried to reproduce the problem without GAE. In order to make python import packages from `lib/` one can set `PYTHONPATH=./lib`.

Comment: The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27?hl=en) tell that the trickery is in calling `vendor.add('lib')` in your `appengine_config.py`. Does it contain the call?

Comment: @void Added my `appengine_config.py` file to question. Its definitely sourcing from the `lib/`

Comment: OK, let's try then heavy artillery. Edit the file `lib/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py` and put the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` just before the statement `import MySQLdb as Database`, approx. in the line 26. Then launch `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` again and try to reproduce the error. The server should fall into the `pdb` session, then enter the following commands: `p sys.executable`, `p sys.exec_prefix`, `p sys.argv`, `p sys.path`, `import _mysql`, `p _mysql` (we expect that the import fails). Then copy the output.

Comment: @void `export PYTHONPATH=./lib` worked my man!
Feel free to write up the answer and you can collect the bounty.

Comment: @ErikÅsland: as already established, the `vendor.add('lib')` function in `appengine_config.py` is supposed to do *just that*, to add the lib directory to the Python `sys.path` configuration.

Comment: @ErikÅsland: I am curious though: why have `MySQLdb` in requirements.txt **at all**? The GAE offers you MySQLdb support via the `libraries` entry in `app.yaml`, and for local development you install `MySQLdb` into the Python library (which is either a virtualenv you used to create your GAE project with or the global site-packages for your Python binary). See [step 5 in the Google Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#Python_Using_a_local_MySQL_instance_during_development).

Comment: @ErikÅsland: thank you and please feel free to edit the answer, you have more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you save my day!, however I was working fine with this configuration since five months, I update my Windows some days ago and then, this error happened. For resolve, I installed MySQLdb in lib folder (GCP recommndations), because I was using integrated libs offer to GCP and misteriously not working anymore for me. Finally I configured my PYTHONPATH and worked like a charm locally. As tip: In your .gitignore  add lines in order to ignore the mysql folders installation :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation was set up according to [Google recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) and it contained no visible errors. The problem could not be reproduced on external environment (a similar Django setup worked fine), so we just came to a workaround, see it below (set `PYTHONPATH`).

GAE requests installing third-party libraries into the `lib/` directory, making it a poor man's virtual environment. Then `lib/` is being added to a module search path by calling `vendor.add('lib')` in the `appengine_config.py`.

That worked correctly in the author's setup, so GAE managed to import Django from `lib/django/`. Then this working config failed misteriously for importing MySQLdb, which was surely installed into the same `lib/`.

During the investigation we have checked the idea if `PYTHONPATH` environment variable could affect anything. It did not, but setting it fixed the issue:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/username/Repositories/projectname/lib/
```

Note: avoid using relative directories in PATH-like environment variables (`./lib` in Erik's comment), that creates a security flaw.

Comment: If you have mysqlclient installed locally, you can configured PYTHONPATH something like this: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: So, today I am rolling back to 220 version : `gcloud components update --version 220.0.0` of gcloud SDK and this problem disappear

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL-Python which is a  C extension,will probably fail(No module named _mysql).
you can give a try with **pymysql** module